# Suppose the characteristic function of random variable $X$ is $ \phi_{X}(x)= cos{\frac{x}{2}}$ what is the distrubition of $X$?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose the characteristic function of random variable $X$ is $ \phi_{X}(x)= cos{\frac{x}{2}}$ what is the distribution  of $X$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is $\mu =\frac {\delta_{1/2} +\delta_{-1/2}} 2$. The distribution function is $F(x)=0$ for $x<-1/2$, $1/2$ for $-1/2 \leq x <1/2$ and 1 for $x \geq 1/2$.